# Identity Server 4: Why i receive unauthorized_client?

Tags: model-view-controller, authorization, identityserver4

This is my initial setting for my mvc connecting with identity server.

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {                
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = "http://identity.azurewebsites.net",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:62419/signin-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:62419/signout-callback-oidc",
            ClientId = "mvc", 
            ResponseType = "id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    var identity = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    var name = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == identity.NameClaimType)?.Value;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

I can get to the identity server. I received a message

> Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
>   Invalid redirect_uri

I have added the redirectUri into the ClientRedirectUris table matched with the code shown above. Is there any other area i forgot to add or set.

Request url:   http://identity.azurewebsites.net/home/error?errorId=CfDJ8BPcf2qEDmRMt0TtYfAIujdUrTeIfqktT2TIcVFNomo6u6QFAROi-gEI2wXHP8kbmmiSYIK1aRV1nL-h6tFY_KeZabkMhIzy-V_0vvo2-hUFfj6I66qJWSjPiRhSYmGZa_-kYlULMb8a1Bz6UQ9UV5L6VdLscQRhScCpnOYpM6Ku84KM_S-4eZXrAX13EaVhqjxhpNhD8jIU9kJkjAn1t6sLVGrfZSEM0tAOGkTXFvBzuoucYURIFhZPJPGjVuJuRegrS2vsLPALHJCv3MLrW9ImudDeCkgf9VhAHwrRLfP3TB_7i4OvEffZwhuDuCSoyQ

Comment: Can you also include the actual request URL that generated this error please?

Comment: I have added the url.. Is that u are looking for.

Comment: No it's the `/connect/authorize` endpoint request which should be before this one in your log.

Comment: I added the RedirectUri in the wrong identityserver database. Now i can have no Invalid redirect_uri error but loginInfo in ExternalLoginCallback function was null and going back to login screen of the identityserver.

Comment: For me, I had to update the table ClientRedirectUris of the Identity Server database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, make sure your scope matches the AlowedScopes in your client configuration. It would help if we could see the request URL. i.e.

```
https://identity.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize?
client_id=mvc
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:62419/signin-oidc
&response_type=id_token
&scope=openid profile
&nonce=63653346343504
&state=CfDJAJDR
&response_mode=form_post
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to make sure the redirect url matches a redirect url in your client configuration in IdentityServer. For example

```
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "mvc",
        ClientName = "MVC Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

        // where to redirect to after login
        RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:62419/signin-oidc" },

        // where to redirect to after logout
        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:62419/signout-callback-oidc" },

        AllowedScopes = new List<string>
        {
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
        }
    }
```

Make sure `RedirectUris` matches the redirect url set in your client 'http://localhost:62419/signin-oidc'

Comment: `http/https` difference in redirect url caused that error in my case. Thanks!