# Skoruba IdentityServer4 admin Simple Project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I want to add an MVC project to the Skoruba template as a new client. In the Sturtup settings of the Mvc project, I did the following:

```
sdfsdfpublic void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
       options.DefaultSignOutScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authorization/AccessDenied";
                    // set session lifetime
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8);
                    // sliding or absolute
                    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                    // host prefixed cookie name
                    options.Cookie.Name = "MVC";
                    // strict SameSite handling
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = Configuration["IDPBaseAddress"];
                    options.ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"];
                    options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                    options.ResponseMode = "query";

                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Home/");
                    options.SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/Home/");

                    options.MapInboundClaims = true;

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("roles");
                    options.Scope.Add("PS.WebApi.Read");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    //options.UsePkce = true;
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(claimType: "role", jsonKey: "role"); // for having 2 or more roles

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
                        RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
                    };
                });
            //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
            //                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                //.RequireAuthorization();

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );
                //.RequireAuthorization();
            });

            //[HttpPost]
            //public IActionResult Logout()
            //{
            //    return SignOut("Cookies", "oidc");
            //}
        }
```

My endpoint projects are as follows:

```
Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin  = https://localhost:44303
Skoruba.IdentityServer4.STS.Identity   = https://localhost:44310
Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api    = https://localhost:44356 
Mvc_Client_Project = https://localhost:44332
```

Configure My Project MVC Settings  (appsettings.json):

```
"WebApiBaseAddress": "https://localhost:44356",
  "IDPBaseAddress": "https://localhost:44310",
  "ClientId": "Mvc_ClientId",
  "ClientSecret": "WebMvc"
```

Contents of the Identityserverdata.json file:

```
{
    "IdentityServerData": {
        "IdentityResources": [
            {
                "Name": "roles",
                "Enabled": true,
                "DisplayName": "Roles",
                "UserClaims": [
                    "role"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "openid",
                "Enabled": true,
                "Required": true,
                "DisplayName": "Your user identifier",
                "UserClaims": [
                    "sub"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "profile",
                "Enabled": true,
                "DisplayName": "User profile",
                "Description": "Your user profile information (first name, last name, etc.)",
                "Emphasize": true,
                "UserClaims": [
                    "name",
                    "family_name",
                    "given_name",
                    "middle_name",
                    "nickname",
                    "preferred_username",
                    "profile",
                    "picture",
                    "website",
                    "gender",
                    "birthdate",
                    "zoneinfo",
                    "locale",
                    "updated_at"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "email",
                "Enabled": true,
                "DisplayName": "Your email address",
                "Emphasize": true,
                "UserClaims": [
                    "email",
                    "email_verified"
                ]
            },
            {
                "Name": "address",
                "Enabled": true,
                "DisplayName": "Your address",
                "Emphasize": true,
                "UserClaims": [
                    "address"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "ApiScopes": [
          {
            "Name": "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api",
            "DisplayName": "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api",
            "Required": true,
            "UserClaims": [
              "role",
              "name"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "WebApi.Read",
            "DisplayName": "WebApi Read",
            "Required": true,
            "UserClaims": [
              "role",
              "WebApi.Read"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "WebApi.Write",
            "DisplayName": "WebApi Write",
            "Required": true,
            "UserClaims": [
              "role",
              "WebApi.Write"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "ApiResources": [
          {
            "Name": "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api",
            "Scopes": [
              "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "WebApi",
            "Scopes": [
              "WebApi.Read",
              "WebApi.Write"
            ]
          }
        ],
      "Clients": [
        {
          "ClientId": "Idp_Admin_ClientId",
          "ClientName": "Idp_Admin_ClientId",
          "ClientUri": "https://localhost:44303",
          "AllowedGrantTypes": [
            "authorization_code"
          ],
          "RequirePkce": true,
          "ClientSecrets": [
            {
              "Value": "Idp_Admin_ClientSecret"
            }
          ],
          "RedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44303/signin-oidc"
          ],
          "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://localhost:44303/signout-oidc",
          "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44303/signout-callback-oidc"
          ],
          "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
            "https://localhost:44303"
          ],
          "AllowedScopes": [
            "openid",
            "email",
            "profile",
            "roles"
          ]
        },
        {
          "ClientId": "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api_swaggerui",
          "ClientName": "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api_swaggerui",
          "AllowedGrantTypes": [
            "authorization_code"
          ],
          "RequireClientSecret": false,
          "RequirePkce": true,
          "RedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44302/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"
          ],
          "AllowedScopes": [
            "Idp_Admin_ClientId_api"
          ],
          "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
            "https://localhost:44302"
          ]
        },
        //WebApi
        {
          "ClientId": "WebApi_ClientId",
          "ClientName": "WebApi_ClientId",
          "ClientUri": "https://localhost:44365",
          "AllowedGrantTypes": [
            "authorization_code"
          ],
          "RequirePkce": true,
          "ClientSecrets": [
            {
              "Value": "WebApi"
            }
          ],
          "RedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44303/signin-oidc"
          ],
          "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://localhost:44303/signout-oidc",
          "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44303/signout-callback-oidc"
          ],
          "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
            "https://localhost:44303",
            "https://localhost:44310"
          ],
          "AllowedScopes": [
            "openid",
            "email",
            "profile",
            "roles"
          ]
        },
        //Mvc
        {
          "ClientId": "Mvc_ClientId",
          "ClientName": "Mvc_ClientId",
          "ClientUri": "https://localhost:44332",
          "AllowedGrantTypes": [
            "hybrid"
          ],
          //"RequirePkce": true,
          "AllowPlainTextPkce": false,
          "ClientSecrets": [
            {
              "Value": "WebMvc"
            }
          ],

          "RedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44332/signin-oidc"
          ],
          "FrontChannelLogoutUri": "https://localhost:44332/signout-oidc",
          "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
            "https://localhost:44332/signout-callback-oidc"
          ],
          "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
            "https://localhost:44332",
            "https://localhost:44310"
          ],
          "AllowedScopes": [
            "openid",
            "email",
            "profile",
            "roles",
            "address",
            "PS.webApi"
          ],
          "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
          "RequireConsent": false,
          "AllowOfflineAccess": true
          //"UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh": true
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

Home controller in My MVC project:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Default()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

But finally, after running and referring to the address
https://localhost:44332/home/privacy

which is decorated with attributes

[Authorize]

I have the following error:

```
Sorry , there was an error : invalid_request 
Invalid Redirect_Uri
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M3pJ.png)
It should be noted that the property is

RequireHttpsMetadata = false

Comment: You have to make sure the redirect url matches a redirect url in your client configuration in IdentityServer.Read this post, it may be helpful to you：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655664/identity-server-4-why-i-receive-unauthorized-client